# Can't access the web inspector on iPad or iPhone

Tags: ios, safari, web-inspector, safari-web-inspector

I'm trying to debug my website (regular website, on Safari, not a standalone app) on my iPhone and iPad.

I enabled Web Inspector on both my iPhone and my iPad.

I then connected them to my Mac, and they showed up in the Develop menu in Safari on the Mac.

However, when I looked at the submenu, it showed "Enable Web Inspector on Device". So I went back to settings on the iPad/iPhone, and disabled and then reenabled Web Inspector. The menu (on the Mac) switched to "No inspectable applications", and then a few seconds later in switched back to "Enable Web Inspector on Device".

How can I get the developer tools to work?

Comment: Having the same issue here, any ideas of what causes that?

Comment: Is 'enable web inspector on device' grayed out on Desktop Safari?

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to perform the following resets:

### **On iOS 16.5**:

1. Access `Settings --> General --> Transfer or Reset iPhone`
2. Reset `Location and Privacy`
3. Reset `Network Settings`
4. Wait till iPhone restarted
5. Connected it to the computer with charging cable
6. Clicked `Trust Device` when prompted
7. Opened Safari on both iOS and Safari, and voilà

Answer (score -1):

`No inspectable applications`
in my case is when I have different app (like preferences) on my iPhone screen. When I come back to mobile safari everything is working good ;).